# omniauth oauth tokens for gmail are invalid

Tags: ruby, oauth, gmail, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to get an oauth token I can use with gmail_xauth (ruby gem) 
to look at a user's mail. I first registered my app with google and 
then set up devise to request access to mail:

```
   config.omniauth :google, 'key', 'secret', :scope => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/'
```

I then go through the outh/openid flow and google prompts me to 
approve access to gmail, redirecting me back to the app with a a token 
and secret in the omniuth credentials & my Google account lists my app 
as authorized to access my data. So far so good.

Now, when I take those credentials and try to use them with 
gmail_xoauth like so:

```
  require 'gmail_xoauth' 
  imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = 
nil, verify = false) 
  imap.authenticate('XOAUTH', '...@gmail.com', 
    :consumer_key => 'key, 
    :consumer_secret => 'secret', 
    :token => 'omniauth_returned_token', 
    :token_secret => 'omniauth_returned_secret' 
  )
```

I get an error "Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Invalid credentials 
(Failure)".

Interestingly, following the gmail_xoauth README to generate a token 
with an same consumer using a python script it does work.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem?

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I had similar problems, but found a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
config.omniauth :google, 'anonymous', 'anonymous', :scope => 'https://mail.google.com/'
```

I'm using the gmail gem, so to connect it looks like this:

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(:xoauth, auth.uid,
  :token           => auth.token,
  :secret          => auth.secret,
  :consumer_key    => 'anonymous',
  :consumer_secret => 'anonymous'
)
```

I'm passing an authentication object in, but you'll be getting it from the env variable **env["omniauth.auth"]**. I'm using anonymous/anonymous for the key/secret since I haven't registered my domain with google, but I believe you can [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains). It'll still work with anonymous/anonymous, but Google will just warn the user.

Comment: anonymous works. Thanks... just wondering how to get the contacts

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore - the secret is nil when I access the omniauth object.  There is a separate link that works at http://blog.asif.in/blog/2012/03/03/google-oauth-and-rails/ but I wasn't able to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Google's OAuth1 protocol is now deprecated and many gems have not yet updated to use their OAuth2 protocol. Here is a working example of fetching email from Google using their OAuth2 protocol. This example uses the [`mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail), [`gmail_xoauth`](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth), [`omniauth`](http://www.omniauth.org/), and [`omniauth-google-oauth2`](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) gems.

You will also need to register your app in [Google's API console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) in order to get your API tokens.

```
# in an initializer:
ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'] = 'yourkey'
ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'] = 'yoursecret'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'], {
    scope: 'https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
  }

end

# ...after handling login with OmniAuth...

# in your script
email = auth_hash[:info][:email]
access_token = auth_hash[:credentials][:token]

imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', email, access_token)
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(['ALL']).each do |message_id|

    msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
    mail = Mail.read_from_string msg

    puts mail.subject
    puts mail.text_part.body.to_s
    puts mail.html_part.body.to_s

end
```

Comment: I still seem to get an error here where I have invalid credentials.

Comment: I get invalid credentials still with this answer.